# Can not called locationManager(_::didUpdateLocations:)

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I tried get the coordinates when user launched app.

I setted up the locationManager code in a independent file:

**UserLocation.swift**:

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class UserLocation: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var userCurrentLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D? 
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    func locationSetup() {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse {
            print("authorization error")
            return
        }
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 300
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        print("startUpdatingLocation")
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            print("locationServicesEnabled")
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print("locationManager getting start")
        if let location = locations.last {
            self.userCurrentLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
            print("print location in locationManager: \(String(describing: userCurrentLocation?.latitude))")
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            
        }
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFinishDeferredUpdatesWithError error: Error?) {
        print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
        return
    }
    
}
```

then, I call the func in the **AppDelegate.swift**'s `application(_::didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        let getUserLocation = UserLocation()
        getUserLocation.locationSetup()
}
```

but , the only calls `locationSetup()` function successfully , never called the related  function locationManager(_::didUpdateLocations:). the `print("locationManager getting start")` I putted the first line in the `locationManager(_::didUpdateLocations:)`, never printed out

BTW, in the info.plist , I already set Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description .

can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getUserLocation` is a local variable. It goes out of existence 1 millisecond after you create it. So it never has time to *do* anything (e.g. location updating). Promote it to an instance variable so that it lives longer:

```
var getUserLocation : UserLocation?
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    self.getUserLocation = UserLocation()
    self.getUserLocation?.locationSetup()
    return true
}
```

(Also please use better variable names. An object reference should not begin with a verb.)

Answer (score 0):

Please cross-check simulator location: **Simulator -> Debug -> Locations** that shouldn't be None in your case...

Hope this will help you... Thanks :)